# My schema.org sturctured data is not showing up on google

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

It's been around a month since I've added structured data on my website. However, Google structured data testing tool is displaying "all is good". The data is not showing up in google (right side when website name is entered in google search)

Here is the jsonld script example,

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ClothingStore",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "locality",
        "postalCode": "395047",
        "addressRegion": "Gujarat",
        "streetAddress": "Address of store"
    },
    "description": "website description.",
    "name": "website.url",
    "alternateName" : "website.url",
    "openingHours": "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa 12:00-22:00",
    "telephone": "+91-7412566478",
    "url": "http://website.url",
    "email": "mail-address@gmail.com",
    "logo": "http://website.url/img/logo.jpg",
    "geo": {
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude": "xx.xxxxxxx",
        "longitude": "xx.xxxxxx"
    },
    "hasMap": "https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/website.url",
    "sameAs": ["https://plus.google.com/+website.url",
                         "https://www.facebook.com/website.url",
                         "https://in.linkedin.com/pub/website.url/xxxx",
                         "https://twitter.com/website.url",
                         "https://www.pinterest.com/website.url"],
    "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://website.url/search.html?ser_type=find&q={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
    },
    "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "ratingValue": "4.5",
            "reviewCount": "250"
     }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry but there is already a handful of questions and answers regarding Google not displaying schema data. You need to wait 1-3 months and even then Google may not decide to display additional information in the serps as it varies from niche to niche, among other things. If it works in the testing tool then watch WMT for it to be indexed, then you need to wait around 1-3 months thereafter before they 'MAY' become visible.

Comment: @SohanPatel check it is seeing structured data in the webmaster tools, and re-crawl with Fetch as google. It may then appear a few days later.

Comment: Can I preview the data before it is indexed in google ? Is it really takes upto 3 months to index and display the rich snippet?

Comment: you can check the structured data with the google structured data testing tool or with the [structured data linter](http://linter.structured-data.org) which will show you what data is found but not exactly how it will look. After doing 'Fetch as google' in the webmaster tools in my experience it takes 2-3 days for changes to take effect. In the webmaster tools you should also see a Structured Data section- check it is finding your data there. I'm not exactly sure how you want the snippet to look, how it looks depends on your search terms. Is it recognizing any data yet?